# How to Add and Remove Footer Links in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom module and then created `default.xml` in `app/code/Test/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
     <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link" remove="true">
     <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-link">
             <arguments>
                 <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Footer Link</argument>
                 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">testuser</argument>
             </arguments>
         </block>
     </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

But its not showing the result.

Answer (score 1):

By Default Magento2 provides some footer links. We need to remove them first. Then create a content block from admin site using the key `footer_links_block` and need to integrate it. For these changes you should create a file

```
app/design/frontend/<vender name>/<theme name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

then place below code into the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_links_block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_links_block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

In Detail, From XML below line is used to remove default footer links

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
```

Below line is used to integrate the content block with key `footer_links_block`

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_links_block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_links_block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

Now you can manage the footer links using content block by admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line  :

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
```

in file `default.xml`:

For Luma Theme, you can edit from (or in your custom theme):

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Comment: I have created a module in which I have added default.xml file

Comment: Try to add this line in default.xml under your module. don't forget to flush cache and deploy content

Comment: I have tried, but it's not working

Comment: I edited my answer, did you flush cache and content deploy ?

Answer (score 0):

by looking at your code,

```
<referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link" remove="true">
```

you didn't put closing sign in this tag.

It should be like this.

```
<referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link" remove="true"/>
```